# How to identify a redirected domain?

Tags: url, redirect, dns, httpresponse

Is it possible to identify a redirected domain?
I have 3 domain> [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) , [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) ,  [www.example3.com](http://www.example3.com)

[www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) domain redirected to  [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com)
[www.example3.com](http://www.example3.com) domain also redirected to  [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com)

How to identify the redirected url is example2 or example3?

Comment: Include some unmistakable, explicit information in the URL while redirecting, that's the only reliable way.

Comment: Did you mean like query strings?

Comment: Query strings, something added to the path… yes, any explicit information that your target server can see.

Comment: Any other suggestions? It is a wordpress site. Any plugins available. I wants to display a popup based on redirected url

Comment: And why would Wordpress require some alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added redirected url with query string at the end of the url and display popup based on query string value.